# Previous expression in clojure repl

Tags: clojure, read-eval-print-loop

In the python repl, getting the result of the previously input expression is easy:

```
>>> 1+2
3
>>> _
3
>>>
```

Is there a way to do this in the clojure repl?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

```
*1
```

Should do it! Similarly, you have access to `*2` and `*3` as well.

Comment: sweet! thanks. and curse stackoverflow for making me wait to accept

Comment: And `*e` for the last exception thrown.